# What API use in Flask to check connection some remote (other) server?

Tags: python, flask

I have some script in regular py file to check connected or not on desired URL.

```
import urllib2
import time
global xUrl
Url = 'http://stackoverflow.com/'

def checkNetwork():
    try:
   response=urllib2.urlopen(Url,timeout=1)
       return True
    except urllib2.URLError as err: pass
    return False

while 1:
   if checkNetwork() == 1:
      print "Connected to", Url
   else:
      print "Cannot Connected to", Url

   time.sleep(5)
   pass
```

For implemented in flask, i did try this:

```
@app.route('/status/')
@auth.login_required
def checkNetwork():
   user = auth.get_logged_in_user()
   optiondetails = Optionplatform.select().where(Optionplatform.user==user.id)  
   xUrl = Optionplatform.remoteserver #i edited the posted questions. 

   try:
      response = urllib2.urlopen(xUrl,timeout=1)
      status = "Connected to " + xUrl
      return render_template('checkNetwork.html', status)
   except urllib2.URLError as err: 
      status = "NOT Connected to " + xUrl
      return render_template('checkNetwork.html', status)

   return render_template('checkNetwork.html')
```

and for the templates,

```
<html>
<head> </head>
<body>
{% block content_details %}

 <p>{{ status }} </p>
{% endblock %}
</body>
</html>
```

But got this error:
[image: Error Messages]
Question is, how implemented in flask ? What API in Flask should be used ? Instead of urllib32 to open some URI and check, connected or not to remote server.

Thanks for anything suggestion.

Edited, according answer/comment from Miguel:
Here the models.

```
class Optionplatform(db.Model):
   user = ForeignKeyField(User, related_name='user_option')
   remoteserver = TextField()
   token = TextField()
```

And according to suggestion by @miguel, before i wrote just like @miguel said:

```
xUrl = optiondetails.remoteserver
```

but later occure error messages that indicates, ther is no "remoteserver" in models.py. Here the error messages "AttributeError: 'SelectQuery' object has no attribute 'remoteserver'".

[image: other error messages]

So i changed to:

```
xUrl = Optionplatform.remoteserver
```

And the error messages is in first images.

Comment: Sorry, but I'm having a very hard time understanding what you are attempting to do. It seems as if you think that Flask is used as a web client (that is, you use Flask to make a connection from your computer to a website like StackOverflow). It is actually the opposite: Flask is meant to allow you to ACCEPT connections: it can be used to CREATE a web site like StackOverflow.

Comment: Not int that way. This was my little experiment to do little internet of things matters (machine to machine) which have communication to other web service (let say build with flask) or others (build with other frameworks). Fyi, i inspired from this idea (http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/73/) and try understanding it to make some test with above script at first. 
Anyway, thanks Mark, for your comment. It is help me understanding this page(http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/deploying/others/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simpler approach, using the excellent [`requests` library](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/)

```
import requests

@app.route('/status/')
@auth.login_required
def checkNetwork():
   user = auth.get_logged_in_user()
   optiondetails = Optionplatform.select().where(Optionplatform.user==user.id)  
   xUrl = optiondetails.remoteserver #i edited the posted questions. 

   status = None
   try:
      r = requests.get(xUrl)
   except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: 
      status = "Network Error while connecting to {}".format(xUrl)

   if r and str(r.status_code)[0] not in ('2','3'):
      status = "URL {} returned {}".format(xUrl, status_code)
   else:
      status = "Connection established to {}".format(xUrl)

   return render_template('checkNetwork.html', status=status)
```

Comment: Bingo.., for requests - lib, looks like so human. Anyway, i think

Comment: I add manually the var xURL=some.ip.address (to test the requests-lib), because the select() issues not fixed yet. And it is works!. looks like request-lib is more human.   

Anyway, i think render_template('checkNetwork.html', status), is only permitted just one argument (TypeError: render_template() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)). To fix this, i change to : render_template('checkNetwork.html',**locals()).

Comment: You need `render_template('checkNetwork.html', status=status)` and *not* `**locals()`.

Answer (score 0):

The `xUrl` argument that you send to `urllib2` needs to be a string (or a `urllib2.Request` object, but that's doesn't seem to be what you want anyway).

From your stack trace it appears xUrl is a `TextField` object from Flask-Peewee instead.

You don't show the definition of your models, but I believe this is the code that is wrong:

```
optiondetails = Option.select().where(Option.user==user.id)
xUrl = Optionp.remoteserver
```

I think instead you want:

```
optiondetails = Option.select().where(Option.user==user.id)
xUrl = optiondetails.remoteserver
```

Or something close, you know your models and I don't, so you'll have to adapt it. The important thing is that you make sure what you put in xUrl is a string with the URL.

Comment: I updated my post, that shown the models. 
My mistaken, not "Optionp", but i mean Optionplatform, which mean calling the model.py. FYI, before my code use this parameter, (and i believe this is the right ones) 

   xUrl = optiondetails.remoteserver

 But later occure error messages that indicates, ther is no "remoteserver" in models.py. Here the error messages "AttributeError: 'SelectQuery' object has no attribute 'remoteserver'". I will add the screenshot for this error in my posted questions.   I